# Extending typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I have component `Checkbox.tsx`, which ts interface looks like:

```
export interface ICheckbox {
    /** DOM element id. */
    id: string;
    /** Handler to the onClick event */
    onCheck?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}
```

Now, I would like to create another component `CheckboxWithLabel.tsx`, which will have a very similar interface, the only additional thing gonna be a label. How can I merge two interfaces or extends existing interface? Something like:

```
import {ICheckbox} from './Checkbox.tsx';

export interface ICheckboxLabel {
    ...ICheckbox,
    label: string;
}
```

What i have tried is:

```
export interface ICheckboxLabel extends ICheckbox{
     children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] | string;
}
```

The problem is, that I don't know if it's the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export an interface by using extends keyword.

```
interface a extends b {
   ...
}
```

In your example it will be like.

```
export interface ICheckboxLabel extends ICheckbox {
   label: string
}
```

Also visit the official documentation for more information https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: You should add a bit of text to the answer.. not just a code snippet ..

Comment: I think it's pretty self explanatory